# Quarter Conversion using casewhen

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a function so I convert the month values to quarters using the case when function.

Then I want to leverage mutate() to create a new variable Qtr and determine how many observations I see in each quarter.

```
convert_to_qtr <- function(Month) {
  case_when(
  Month == "Jan" ~ "Q1",
  Month == "Feb" ~ "Q1",
  Month == "Mar" ~ "Q1",
  Month == "Apr" ~ "Q2", 
  Month == "May" ~ "Q2", 
  Month == "Jun" ~ "Q2",
  Month == "Jul" ~ "Q3", 
  Month == "Aug" ~ "Q3", 
  Month == "Sep" ~ "Q3",
  Month == "Oct" ~ "Q4", 
  Month == "Nov" ~ "Q4", 
  Month == "Dec" ~ "Q4"
)
}

example_months <- c("Jan", "Mar", "May", "May", "Aug", "Nov", "Nov", "Dec")
convert_to_qtr(example_months)


df %>%
mutate(Qtr = convert_to_qtr(Month)) %>%
  group_by(Qtr) %>%
  count(Qtr)
```

However I am not getting the same answer as my professor in his drop down so I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in my r coding.

He sees the numbers 161,071 85,588 100,227 142,651

I am not getting that, I see 152174 165778 205615 174592

[image]

Comment: We can't reproduce this without an example of your data frame. Another possibility is to ask your professor or a TA.

Comment: How can I attach a file? @Phil

Comment: You can use `dput(mydf)` with `mydf` being whatever your data frame is called, and copy/paste the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the function as below:

```
convert_to_qtr <- function(Month){
  setNames(paste0("Q", rep(1:4,each=3)), month.abb)[Month]
}

df %>%
   mutate(Qtr = convert_to_qtr(Month)) %>%
   count(Qtr)
  Qtr  n
1  Q1 29
2  Q2 24
3  Q3 26
4  Q4 21
```

Comment: yes I agree with your coding but I am still not getting the drop down options from the professor suggestions

here is the data - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17zT9VU11gzutxhBs1dv7Z0o6D9FLiBk_?usp=sharing

Comment: This is what I got this morning "You need to determine which quarter each observation falls in and then just tally the total number of observations for each quarter."